# Can I see business hours in my local timezone on Google Now and Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-now, time-zones

It would be useful to have a business's hours displayed in both the business's timezone and my own.  As of now, search results only shows the time in the business's timezone, forcing me to convert before I try making a phone call.